# rolling sum depending on a another column value

Tags: sql, impala

I have table data like below

```
Country    roll   value
us          0      100
us          0      200
us          1      50
us          1      250
us          1      350
us          0      75
cn          1     500
cn          0     200
cn          1     300
```

I want out put inserted to other table as below

```
Country    roll   value  rollingsum
us          0      100     100
us          0      200     200
us          1      50      250(200+50)
us          1      250     500(250+250)
us          1      350     850(500+350)
us          0      75      75
cn          1     500      500
cn          0     200      200
cn          1     300      500
```

If column roll=1 then I want to add the previous value with value column in the row. If next value of roll is 1 then add the previous rolling sum value with current value . Please let me know how can we get this

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to have an ordering in mind but it is not in the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.  The following assumes there is one

You can assign groups to rows for the assignment.  The grouping is the number of 0s up-to and including the row.  Then use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (partition by country, grp
                        order by <ordering col>
                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                       ) as 
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when roll = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by country
                                                             order by <ordering col>
                                                             rows between rollingsumunbounded preceding and current row
                                                            ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Sorry there is ordering I forgot to add another column which has sequence number . "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" is not supported in my version of Hadoop database . Can we have other approach.Thanks.

Comment: @user1024962 . . . You can leave out the window frame, because that is the default.  Hadoop has supported window functions for . . . well basically forever as far as I know.